# How to Flatten and stack Efficiently 50000 Images

Tags: import, image, memory

I have 50000 grayscale images with 56*56 pixels each one. I need to flatten images and stakck it in the same array with dimensions 50000*3136 after that export the file as .CSV.
I am doing this code which load all images in the memory which can cause a problem if we have not enough memory space.

```
imagesToArray[pathsrc_, pathdes_] := Module[{filesList, data}, (
   (* pathsrc_ : list of images path *)
   (* pathdes_ : CSV file path*)

   filesList = FileNames["*.png", pathsrc];
   Print["Number of images :", Length@filesList];
   data = 
    Table[Flatten[ImageData[Import[filesList[[i]]]]], {i, 1, 
      Length@filesList}];
   Export[pathdes, data];
   data
   )]
```

Is there any alternative to do it faster without memory problem?

Comment: Why not `data = Flatten [ ImageData /@ Import /@ fileList ]` instead of `Table[ ]`? Am I missing something?

Comment: anyway, importing 50K images will take quite a long time

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, may be it will be faster but I think it load all data  in memory

Comment: Why would you store such a large amount of binary data in csv?  In any case you can read each file and write on the fly so you don't load everything in memory at once, you need to forgo `Export` to achieve that though.

Comment: @george2079, I am doing a dataset like MNIST and I need to publish it

Comment: If you can forgo all the behind-the-scene checking that `Import` does, you can try using the built-in function that Import ultimately calls to read in a PNG file, which is ``Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG``. It returns a list containing the image imported. You can use e.g. ``First@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[pathToImage]`` to get each image. It is roughly 10x faster than using `Import`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine [@nikie's approach above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110424/27951) with the use of a **faster built-in import function**.

If you can forgo all the behind-the-scene checking that `Import` does, you can try using the built-in function that `Import` ultimately calls to read in a PNG file, which is `` Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG ``. I found that out by using `Trace@Import[somePNGfile]` and wading through *quite a lot* of output. Incidentally, the counterpart to this function also exists, i.e. `ImageWritePNG`, but it requires multiple arguments and I haven't figured that one out yet; however, `Export` is already quite a bit zippier than `Import` at least for PNG files, so the need is less pronounced there.

It returns a list containing the image imported. To get each image, you can use e.g.

```
First@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[pathToImage]
```

It is at least 10x faster than using `Import`, and quite possibly more.

For instance, let's generate 200 small PNGs of the kind you are working with:

```
MapIndexed[
  Export["images\\" <> ToString[First@#2] <> ".png", #1] &,
  Image /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {200, 56, 56}]
];
```

Now let's compare timings:

```
First@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG["images\\" <> ToString[#] <> ".png"] & /@ 
   Range[1, 200]; // AbsoluteTiming

Import["images\\" <> ToString[#] <> ".png"] & /@ Range[1, 200]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out:
{0.221601, Null}
{15.5932, Null}
*)
```

That's a **70x speedup**!

Comment: Awesome!Does the same things can be happened in “.JPG”?Like something `ImageReadJPG`?

Comment: I did notnrun this code, I get this error **{$Failed, 2}** and this function seems not defined because it colored in blue

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How does we get the help about this kind of function. Is it really a built-in function? I have looked in the help but i did not get any infos! It seems magic !

Comment: @Developer2000 Try evaluating the following: ``Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[]``. Although the function name will *not* be recognized (i.e. it will stay blue), you should obtain the following output: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/D526D.png). If you do, then the code above should work for you as well. You may also want to check that all the finicky backticks, etc. were copied correctly to your notebook.

Comment: despite that I get the out put as you mentioned but call the function with the path, I get ** {$Failed, 2} ** and on the terminal I get **libpng error: Read Error**

Comment: @Developer2000 So ``Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[somePath]`` throws an error. Try running `Import[thatSamePath]`: does that work? or does it also throw an error? What error do you get in that case?

Comment: It works fine with Import

Comment: @Developer2000 Could you share a link to one of your images? e.g. dropbox or some such?

Comment: I tried on mathematica 10.1 on Mac and on mathematica 10.3 on linux and I get the same problem. Here is an image https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdxgv92rjf1tfzo/001.png?dl=0. These Images are processed and Exported as .png using mathematica

Comment: @Developer2000 It works fine on my side: [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XNmMF.png). Weird. I am using MMA 10.4 on Win7-64bit. What about you?

Comment: @yode Try ``Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadJPEG`` :-)

Comment: I am running Mathematica 10.3 on linux debian

Comment: Thanks a lot.I like this answer very much.And then do you mean ``Image`ImportExportDump``  requires multiple arguments ?But ``Image`ImportExportDump`ImageWritePNG["1.png",Image@RandomReal[{0,1},{200,56,3}]]`` work well in my 10.4.0.It speed up many times than `Export` too.

Comment: @yode That's great! I had not yet played with the `ImageWritePNG` function at all. It's nice to see that it accepts an `Export`-like syntax. However, the speed difference is less impressive on export. Using `img = Image@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3000, 3000}]`, it takes my computer 2.16s to export with `ImageWritePNG`, and 2.77s with plain `Export`, for a speedup of only 1.28x, i.e. way smaller than the one observed when importing pictures.

Comment: Yup.`Import` is 3.35 and another is 5.63 in here.But anyway,it is a good news.And very appreciate your black tech.:)

Answer (score 5):

You can use stream functions, like this (untested):

```
f = OpenWrite[pathdes];
chunkSize = 100;
Monitor[Do[
  (
     lines=ParallelTable[Flatten[ImageData[Import[filesList[[j]]]]],
            {j,i,Min[i+chunkSize-1,Length@filesList]}];
     WriteString[f, ExportString[lines, "CSV"]];
  ), 
  {i, 1, Length@filesList, chunkSize}], i];
Close[f];
```

to avoid the memory cost. I'd guess `Import` would be the bottleneck in that code, and there's not much you can do to make it faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not gain more time than mine with 500 images: My solution gives 44s and yours gives 42s.

Comment: Like I said, you can avoid the memory cost, but there's not much you can do to improve `Import`'s speed without rewriting the functionality.