# Delete all mostly white images in a folder

Tags: image-processing, color, image

I need to delete images that are all or mostly white, here's a sample of them:

[image]

Here is my my code finds, my code is not very accurate nor efficient:

```
WhiteQ[img_] := ColorDistance[DominantColors[img, 1], White][[1]] < 0.2
fimgs = Map[
  Framed[#, FrameStyle -> If[WhiteQ[#], {Thick, Red}, White]] &, 
  imgs]
Magnify[Grid[Partition[fimgs, 10], Dividers -> All], 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps define "mostly", and provide some images to play with?

Comment: Sure, maybe 97% of area is white, it doesn't have to be exactly. And whats the easiest way that can I provide the images?

Comment: Perhaps a google Drive or dropbox link, or similar services?

Comment: With the Wolfram Cloud, I put the images into Databin 'dsNFr2og'.  https://wolfr.am/dsNFr2og

Comment: @MarcoB The permissions on the databin is public, can you access it?

Comment: Yes, I was able to access it fine from within Mathematica. That's was good idea to use Wolfram's own feature, I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Databin link.

Answer (score 3):

This seems pretty fast (it takes roughly 0.08s on your set of images):

```
images = Normal@Databin["dsNFr2og"];

Total[#, 2] & /@ ImageData /@ Binarize /@ images;
% / (Times @@ ImageDimensions[images[[1]]]) // N;
Extract[images, Position[%, p_ /; p < 0.5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Adjust the `0.5` threshold to your liking to retain more or fewer images. (Thanks nikie for the suggestion to replace `Count` with `Total`!).

Using a fixed threshold for `Binarize` also leads to a significant speedup:

```
Total[#, 2] & /@ ImageData /@ (Binarize[#, 0.9] & /@ images); // RepeatedTiming
(* Out: {0.016, Null} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That "0.1" seem to not include that import and export?

Comment: @yode sure, but OP already has those images imported. I think it's the processing that took time.

Comment: If you replace `Count[1]` with `Total` (should be the same for binary images?), and if you used a fixed threshold for `Binarize`, you can get that down to about .01s

Comment: @nikie That's a very good point about `Total`; I'll make the change; additionally, using the second argument of `Total` removes the need for `Flatten` as well, and it saves a few ms more. A fixed threshold for `Binarize` is faster, but the default adaptive algorithm seems to give better results (more uniform color blocks in the B&W images). On that point, I'll leave it up to OP to choose which one is more important to him, speed or accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose all your images to process is in a certain same local fold and they are a same format.In this solution,I give a example that they are all ".png".Of course they can be ".tiff",".jpg" or other something.Let simulate your real case

```
images = Normal@Databin["dsNFr2og"];
SeedRandom[1]; 
Export[
   FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "testFold", 
      RandomWord[Language -> "English"]}] <> ".png", #] & /@ images;
```

Start to process,I make a custom function for this.

```
DeleteWihtePicture[fold_, threshold_] := 
 Module[{count = 0}, SetDirectory[fold];
  Do[If[ImageMeasurements[ChanVeseBinarize[#, White], "Total"]/
        Times @@ ImageDimensions[#] &[
      First@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[img]] > threshold, 
    DeleteFile[img]; count++], {img, FileNames[]}]; 
  Print[TemplateApply["You have deleted `` white picture", count]]
   ResetDirectory[];]
```

Let's give a try.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 DeleteWihtePicture[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "testFold"}], .6]]
```

> You have deleted 35 white picture
>
> {0.659116,Null}

Then you will get

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-06-15-08-14-48.png

I don't like these filenames,because they may include some nouns that you don't like. But don't mind that.For the efficiency,I use `` ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG ``.You can replace `` First@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG `` with `Import` for any image format.In my PC(i7-6500U),the time will increase to `1.28`.BTW,you can find those specific function which can help to speed up by

```
Names["Image`ImportExportDump`*"]
```

It is @MarcoB's contribution in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110439/21532),which makes me deeply impressed.Hope this can help.

Comment: "I don't like these filenames,because it can be include some nouns that you don't like." - neither do I; what the hell is an insecticide doing in there?! :P

Comment: @J.M. Ok.I have killed those pests. :)